# Error installing @tensorflow/tfjs-node

Tags: tensorflow, npm-install, tensorflow.js

I'm following a ML tutorial on Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdErOpUzupY&index=5&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABWLy_XoLSxTVRe2bltV8GM) and I'm suppose to install @tensorflow/tfjs-node. However when I run

```
npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node
```

I get the following error (see [screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phCG0.png)).

I've watched the relevant files be placed into `node_modules` but then they immediately get uninstalled. I'm not sure where to go from here, but let me know if you need anymore info.

Cheers

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "tfjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "iris.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel --target=node iris.js & nodemon dist/iris.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^0.11.7",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^0.1.7",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
    "parcel": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: follow : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_java

Comment: Would I need to install this for Java if I'm only using JavaScript in my current app?

Comment: ohh my apologies: this should be helpful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z57aeO1ZYXc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the error screenshot of your errors, you're using node version 6 whereas `tensorflowjs` requires node `v8.9+`. Consider upgrading the version of your server node using the official website [here](https://nodejs.org/en/). When you're done check the version with `node -v` to make sure that your version of node meets the requirements of `tensorflowjs modules`.